# How can I find current element text on mouseover using Angular?

Tags: angular

This is my code:

```
 <ng-material-multilevel-menu (mouseover)="callMe($event)" mat-raised-button matTooltip={{tool}} [configuration]='config' class="nav" [items]='appItems'
            (selectedItem)="selectedItem($event)" (selectedLabel)="selectedLabel($event)">
          </ng-material-multilevel-menu>
        </nav>
```

My CallMe() function:

```
 callMe($event){
    console.log("Hello");
    console.log("event",$event);
  }
```

How can I display the label name on mouseover event ?

Comment: Have you tried $event.explicitOriginalTarget.innerText?

Comment: No. Can you please elaborate a little bit

Comment: Well, in your callMe function, if you log $event.explicitOriginalTarget.innerText, does it show the label name? If yes, you can use that do show it. Or is the problem not how to get the label name but how to display it?

Comment: No, it is not showing label name. If I console log $event.explicitOriginalTarget.innerText it is showing "Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** 
Using the DOM html javascript

```js
<ng-material-multilevel-menu onmouseover="callMe(this)" mat-raised-button matTooltip={{tool}} [configuration]='config' class="nav" [items]='appItems'
            (selectedItem)="selectedItem($event)" (selectedLabel)="selectedLabel($event)">
          </ng-material-multilevel-menu>
        </nav>
```

in **index.html**

```js
<script>
        function callMe(x) {
            console.log(x)
        }
</script>
```

**Solution 2**
Using typescript file

```html
<ng-material-multilevel-menu (mouseover)="callMe($event)" mat-raised-button matTooltip={{tool}} [configuration]='config' class="nav" [items]='appItems'
            (selectedItem)="selectedItem($event)" (selectedLabel)="selectedLabel($event)">
          </ng-material-multilevel-menu>
        </nav>
```

in **typescript file**

```js
callMe(x) {
    console.log(x.fromElement.innerHTML)
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(x.fromElement.innerHTML, "text/html");
    console.log(doc.firstChild)
    console.log(doc.firstChild.lastChild.lastChild)
  }
```